# NSJSONSerialization not working right. Cant't log the jsondata from url

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, nsjsonserialization

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSURL *sURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"TheURLtoJSONData"];

    NSData *jsonData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:sermonURL];



    NSError *error = nil;

    NSDictionary *dataDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:0 error:&error];
    NSLog(@"%@",dataDictionary);

    self.sermonPosts = [dataDictionary objectForKey:@"item"];


}
```

I just want to parse simple JSON data from an url. And to test if it works I use NSLog but nothing is logged. It just says:

> [2674:60b] (null)

I've tried searching most similar questions here but I can't find what i'm looking for. 
Please look at my code. What am I doing wrong. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: What did it say when you `NSLog(@"%p: %@", jsonData, error);`?

Comment: What's the point of passing an error parameter to the JSON deserialiser and not checking it for the reason for the failure? Where have you put breakpoints to check that the objects you are using are what you expect them to be?

Comment: It's hard to evaluate the problem when you don't include the actual URL. An incorrect URL or incorrectly formatted data could be part of the problem.

Comment: It is logging something. It's telling you that `dataDictionary` is `nil`, which is the expected return value when an error occurs.

Comment: BTW, when you solve your immediate problem, you should eventually replace `dataWithContentsOfURL` with an asynchronous retrieval (e.g. `NSURLConnection` method `sendAsynchronousRequest`). You should never do synchronous requests on the main queue (app will be less responsive, the watchdog process could kill your app if it's too slow starting up, etc.).

Comment: Sorry, I'm a beginner. I found out that the url was incorrect. @Rob thank you for the advise about the asynchronous request.